# Python - Can't pass tuple as an argument to another module

Tags: python

First of all, I should tell I'm totally newbie in Python!
So, I may be trying to do something impossible, or something that should be done in a different way. I can't find on the Internet any example about it.

I have two modules in .py. The server.py and the delay_simulator.py. I want to pass a tuple as an argument when I call from server to delay_simulator. But I can't receive the tuple argument in the delay_simulator module.

I will put the code below. Note that the tuple is pkt_recv.

**server.py** (just part of the code)

```
import delay_simulator
from collections import namedtuple
pkt = namedtuple("pkt", ["seq_num", "pkt_type", "data"])
. . .
# !!! - Here is where I call the other module and try to pass the tuple pkt_recv
returned_object = delay_simulator ("string", pkt_recv, prob_loss, rtt, average_delay)
```

**delay_simulator.py** (just part of the code)

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
pkt = namedtuple("pkt", ["seq_num", "pkt_type", "data"])
. . .
caller = str(sys.argv[1])
# !!! - Here is where I can't receive the tuple
pkt_recv = pkt(sys.argv[2])
prob_loss = float(sys.argv[3])
rtt = float(sys.argv[4])
average_delay = float(sys.argv[5])
```

When I run the program server.py, the module delay_simulator.py cannot recognize the second argument, it behaves as if it does not exist!
Is the sys.argv the wrong function to use? Is there another way to pass these arguments, including a tuple?

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: Modules can't be called.  You could write a function and call that.  Have you read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)?

Comment: Not as I should. Thanks, I needed this insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the variable from one module to the next you need to encapsulate it in a function. Try this:

server.py (just part of the code)

```
import delay_simulator
from collections import namedtuple
pkt = namedtuple("pkt", ["seq_num", "pkt_type", "data"])
. . .
# !!! - Here is where I call the other module and try to pass the tuple pkt_recv
returned_object = delay_simulator.getTuple("string", pkt_recv, prob_loss, rtt, average_delay)
```

delay_simulator.py (just part of the code)

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
pkt = namedtuple("pkt", ["seq_num", "pkt_type", "data"])
. . .

def getTuple(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    caller = str(sys.arg1)
    pkt_recv = pkt(sys.arg2)
    prob_loss = float(sys.arg3)
    rtt = float(sys.arg4)
    average_delay = float(sys.arg5)

    return (caller, pkt_recv, prob_loss, rtt, average_delay)
```